# Android Google Maps Api v2 current Location Null

Tags: android, null, maps

Good Day.Im trying to get current location with `map.getMyLocation()` but surely I'm getting NullPointerException as my location isn't loaded for a while.So I'm doing a MapReady check and MapLoaded check which both triggers once map ready and its loaded,but unfortunately  what about my current location,it seems that i will never know when its available.Here is a snippet of my code which i though might do normal null check.

```
            @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {
        //here my map is loaded so this triggers.
    if(map.getMyLocation()!=null){
//do something here. 

    }
        }
```

but it seems that my null check will never work as just because once my above written method triggers it dont wait for my if condition its just checks if it is not satisfying my if condition just going over it so my if condition never triggers.Problem is that how can i be notified when my location is enabled?I tried even to put this into loop of `while()` but its freezes if i do on `UI thread` and won't let me do anything if i do on a `THREAD` as google maps need to be done on `MainThread`.So my question is next,how in world i can be notified whether my location is null,or not?And how can i trigger some piece of code once its not `NULL`?

Comment: means you want to check that your device gps is on or off??

Comment: no,i do that check beforehand,means that i can't predict when that blue circle of current location is available,but seems GOOGLE 'CLEVER' brains didn't get that point,so i need something which will trigger once that blue circle of current location is shown on map,which i can't find in google maps api..

Comment: Ok when map is load you want to go your current location ??

Comment: YES your right and i want to get it only with this code 'map.getMyLocation' as I'm going to play around with this code afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code in my application..
 Try Implement this in you app

```
//Global Declaration
GoogleMap googleMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate;

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

    location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        LatLng latLang = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLang, 17);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    } else {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapScreen.this);
        builder.setTitle("Warning");
        builder.setMessage("Location Not Found...!!!");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();
    }
} else {
    showAlertDialog();
}

private void showAlertDialog () {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapScreen.this);
    builder.setTitle("Warning");
    builder.setMessage("Device GPS is currently OFF. Please Turn ON.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    }).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,before i implement this one question,will this code trigger till current location enabled?or will java run this code and see that current location is null and pass over conditions?

Comment: Implement this code and Debug this code You will find your ans easily... :)

Comment: Thank you very much.Not what i was looking for,though i just implemented and put warning that location will be automatically updated:D unfrotunatally its not our issue its GOOGLES dumb google developers issue..you can produce such kind of apis....its out of mind anyway thank you very much for help